ScrollViewReader scrollTo not working in Form when .id() is used inside VStack
When using a Form and embedding the items in the form in VStacks, ScrollViewReader's scrollTo(...) is not working. Without the VStacks it does.
Is there a solution while keeping the VStacks?
Sample code:
import SwiftUI

struct FormScrollVStackView: View {
    @State var useVStack = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text("Form Scroll VStack").font(.largeTitle)
            Toggle("Use VStack", isOn: $useVStack).frame(maxWidth: 200)
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                Form {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                        if useVStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Item #\(i)").id(i).frame(height: 44)
                            }
                        } else {
                            Text("Item #\(i)").id(i).frame(height: 44)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation {
                                    proxy.scrollTo(i, anchor: .center)
                                }
                            }, label: { Text("#\(i)") })
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(4)
                    .background { Color.yellow }
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 1)
                }
            } // ... ScrollViewReader
        } // ... VStack
    } // ... body
}

#Preview {
    FormScrollVStackView()
}

Easier to test in landscape mode, preview is enough. When activating the "Use VStack" toggle and tapping on the buttons, the scrollTo is not causing a scroll. A screenshot of how the view looks:

Is there a solution apart from applying .id() to the VStacks?
Is there an explanation, why it does not work?
(Xcode 15.4)

Edit:
Interestingly the issue occurs with a Form, but not with a ScrollView. If you replace Form { ... } with ScrollView { ... }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity) the scrolling works with and without the VStacks.

I assume you can't just put id on the VStack because you want to scroll to a specific view in the VStack?

@Sweeper A little bit. But of course if it turns out it must be the VStack, then that it will be

It makes sense. The ScrollView recognizes the outermost view ID to .scrollTo.

Scans all scroll views contained by the proxy for the first
with a child view with identifier id, and then scrolls to
that view.

So the correct way is:
VStack {
    Text("Item #\(i)").frame(height: 44)
}
.id(i) //<- here


Interestingly with a ScrollView instead of a Form it works even with the .id() inside the VStacks.

Given that SwiftUI's source code is not publicly available, I believe it is best to stick to the documentation. Who knows what happens.
